# Angular 5 Not Navigating

Tags: angular5

I'm using the route.navigate(['page']); conditionally and it does not work.

e.g

```
constructor(private route: Router){}

if(data.user != null) {
    this.route.navigate(['page']);
} else {
    alert('Please Login');
}
```

The URL changes but the page don't render.

This is my App Route Module
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

```
// App Components
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ResultsListComponent } from './results-list/results-list.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';
import { AffordabilityComponent } from 
'./affordability/affordability.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { ShowroomComponent } from './showroom/showroom.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { OffersComponent } from './offers/offers.component';
import { AdminHeaderComponent } from './admin-header/admin- 
header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { DealerProfileComponent } from './dealer-profile/dealer- 
profile.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    // { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'search_results', component: ResultsListComponent },
    { path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent },
    { path: 'results', component: AffordabilityComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'showroom', component: ShowroomComponent },
    { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'offers', component: OffersComponent },
    { path: 'profile', component: DealerProfileComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents = [
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ResultsListComponent,
    SigninComponent,
    AffordabilityComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    ShowroomComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    OffersComponent,
    AdminHeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    DealerProfileComponent
];
```

Comment: Please show app-routing.module.ts

Comment: Code added above

Comment: Where you have path: 'page' there? I can't find it

Comment: That was just an example, i'm actually redirecting to "signin"

Comment: Can't find an error here, everything looks ok

Comment: I couldn't find it too, but the damn thing does not render the expected page.

Comment: Please try with: this.route.navigate(['/signin']);